# Patrón de formato en fechas

Tags: java, date

Estoy tratando de generar una fecha con un formato como el siguiente:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("??????") -> ""2019-07-02T10:54:55.440Z"
```

Pero ahora mismo la mayor aproximación que he tenido a este formato es el siguiente:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.sssZ")  ->  "2019-07-183T12:34:12.012+0200"
```

Me he basado en la página del estándar UTC pero no he sido capaz de replicar el formato de la primera sentencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta añadir comillas simples a la `Z` para obtener bien el formato, y ponerle `UTC` como `TimeZone`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

[Enlace de la respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087/what-is-this-date-format-2011-08-12t201746-384z)

Comment: He probado y el formato esta perfecto. Pero la hora que me pone es mi hora local(la que capta del equipo). ¿Obtener esa hora en formato +0, sería posible?